# Can we get "Print Friendly" versions of Teams questions?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I like teams...no in fact [I love using teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380169/thanks-to-so-for-team-devs-designers-pms-etc). One thing that lacks is only "team" members can view or create question and answers. But there is always a time I need to submit a question / answer to someone to read (like a VP or manager). They are not really folks that are involved in asking or answering questions, sometimes they just want to know how something is being solved (think lesson learned migration from a 2005 to 2017 SQL instance).

I documented all of our lessons learned via an SO Team Q & A. It works out well because as soon as I remember something else I'll edit it in, etc.  Confluence for teams is similar to SO Teams in that you can only add content if you are a registered user (take up a license) but the key difference is Confluence for teams allows you "Print Friendly PDF" option on the top of each Confluence page.  Whenever a non-licensed (not registered user) may need information or read something I can spit out a nice .pdf version of it in Confluence for teams and send it to them as an attachment over say email.

This is a nice to have for folks who don't have a license whom you want to share some information with (think that same VP / Manager).

Can we have something similar in SO teams?

I cannot use the browser based "print to .pdf" because it looks kinda cruddy.  Since Teams isn't like Stack Overflow in that it isn't public (share doesn't really work nor does going directly to the URL).

Is this possible to add?

Comment: So let me distill this into the pessimistic version.  You want to share content with someone who isn't licensed to use the service?  Why can they not be licensed?  Why *wouldn't* they be licensed?

Comment: No they don’t need to be licensed because they wont be asking or answering. Similar to a confluence page. If you create a page you can export a pdf to send to someone who does not have a license.  Its totally not cool to charge and use a license if someone is just reading. That is why many many systems provide this.

Comment: Then perhaps a better (more universal) option than a "print friendly" view would be a "view only" user option?

Comment: If it uses a license its no good. Otherwise ok

Comment: I thought to myself "surely it's already fairly print friendly" and hit Ctrl P on this page. Wow... talk about a mess...

Comment: @CodyGray that may entail months or years worth of work. Remember by introducing that youll need to handle any edits including tags, a new administration ui, and authentication. Short term pdf can take a few dev days.

Comment: @Shadow  I mentioned that in my post

Comment: @JonH I didn't realise just how bad it was until I saw it myself :P

Comment: Now that Teams is at stake, `@media:print` should get some love

Comment: "One thing that lacks is only "team" members can view or create question and answers." This seems quite obviously *by design*...

Comment: Tyler please read the entire question not just that one sentence.

Answer (score 6):

**This does not include the answer instead it'll only cover the question, so it's not useful for this purpose. But I think it's still interesting enought to not be deleted.**

Not exactly what you want but it is a good(?) workaround for your problem:

You can use the "Reading mode" that many modern browsers have (for supported sites) to get a "print friendly" Layout.

In Firefox it's a button in the addressbar that looks like a sheet of paper.

Here is a little example:

Without reading mode:
[image: Without reading mode]

With reading mode:
[image: With reading mode]

(These are screenshots of "printed" PDFs.)

Comment: Safari renders this page superbly too, though it only gives you the question (not the answer!)

Comment: It's exactly the same in FF. You get only the question, which seems quite useless if you want to share a Q&A. If you were to do something like that, you wouldn't want to lose the answer, comments, even the score or tags could be useful. I think this workaround is pretty poor.

Comment: Interesting... I am sure I used that feature already to read some Q&A on the arcade stack to get rid of the "colorful" design because I was at work... But you are right... I tried it just now and it also only gave me the question.

Comment: Vivaldi shows both Q&A on Reader View but **only** if it's 1 answer, if there are 2 or more answers it shows only the Q... Usernames don't show up and the header is quite funky.