# Is there a way to hide Stack Overflow related links in the Stack Overflow for Teams product pages?

Tags: support, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams, hyperlinks

I am currently struggling to implement Stack Overflow for Teams where I work and I had several presentation for various departments to extend the usage and also get some feedback before a presentation I have to make for the upper management.

Part of the feedback is related to some UI elements that do not seem to belong in a paid platform:

**1. Products link (upper-right)**

[image: Products link]

**2. Return to Stack Overflow**. This is particularly confusing because it makes Stack Overflow for Teams as a big parenthesis within user activity suggesting that the user really belongs on the public site, not within our private platform.

[image: Return to Stack Overflow]

3. The footer which virtually contains only public Stack Overflow links. This is the least problematic since you typically have to scroll to see that plethora of links.

Personally I do not mind because I am used to ignore this stuff, but I understand why others might get confused, especially that the vast majority of the users did not even had a Stack Overflow account before joining the private team.

I have explained that this is part of a product made by Stack Overflow, but some argued that since we are paying, we should only have relevant content.

**Question:** Is there a way to hide Stack Overflow related links in Stack Overflow for Teams product pages?

P.S. I am thinking about using [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) or similar to remove these sections, but currently the policy forbids Chrome extensions and getting this involves a Kafkaesque process.

Comment: If you can't use extensions then there's not much you can do...

Comment: I am absolutely clueless about this part of the domain, but shouldn't this be [a support ticket](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/tickets/new)?

Comment: @Kaiido - yes, I will ask support about this, but I thought an answer would be useful for more than just me.

Comment: @Kaiido - currently there are [247 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams) about Stack Overflow for Teams here so clearly this is a good place to ask. One good reason to ask here is that the community typically answers faster and might provide a solution to the issue before Stack Overflow is able to fix an issue.

Comment: I don't disagree that those UI choices are perhaps a bit odd, but is this _really_ likely to be a barrier to acceptance for your team? That seems strange to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't work with the OP but I can *definitely* attest to these kinds of things (and less) being barriers in specialized environments -- it doesn't take much to force a user down the path of least resistance; and also to the fact that even seemingly inconsequential barriers (like a user deciding to use email instead of private SO) can lead to huge management headaches/facepalms when it becomes a systemic behavior. Also consider, if the OP received feedback about it, it's necessarily on some users' minds; there are many other things that *didn't* receive comments.

Comment: To answer your question - no, there isn't. You can use a userscript, but without that, the only option left is adding a feature request and hope they implement it (wouldn't bet on it happening though - they have a terrible feature request implementation rate, or even FR response rate atm). So if userscripts aren't an option, you'll have to wait

Comment: Can we have the opposite as well?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be a bummer again, but we're not going to implement the ability to set custom CSS in Team. As suggested, something like TamperMokey would be the only solution.

Answer (score -32):

Stackoverflow for teams was not written for me or you...it was written for **anyone** and **integrated** with stackoverflow in general.  What you are asking for is a custom implementation - you want to separate your team vs what is on stackoverflow.  What is separated is the data, however, the navigation is not separate.  Teams is built upon stackoverflow and you will not be able to change this.

Your question reads to me as if you showed the product and confused "non-programmers" who think them posting a question would somehow get lost in the public site.  This is not true, the data is actually in different databases.  To me it sounds like you are convincing the wrong person(s) or audience.

Most good programmers or programmers who are trying to make a career programming understand this structure.  Others who may be in a different position may be confused because they do not know how the stackexchange platform works.  "Why do I see all those footer links, so confusing"...no this is simply the way SO for teams was written.  It has been written on top of the existing public tool.

My advice to you:

If you are trying to become a better programmer and make your teammates better programmers and your company is giving you grief over that than it is an indication to find better work.  We use SO for teams at my former place and I implemented it in my current workplace and I truly love this tool.  It has not replaced confluence, or github, or slack because it has its own purpose.  In fact, I do not want it replacing anything - it does what I need it to do.  The integrations it has is enough and I hope it stays this way.

Are there things I [wish it had](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380176/can-we-get-print-friendly-versions-of-teams-questions)?  Certainly, but those can come later...

Comment: A simple feature to allow Teams admins to apply custom CSS isn't too much to ask, surely.

Comment: As already mentioned, I do not mind those elements. But there are also other people usi ng teams in our organization and they think differently. Especially the managers.

Comment: I'm not sure where OP asked for help to be a good programmer. I don't think it's the point of SOFT either. Unless it is, in which case all those ads have really missed the mark.

Comment: Being able to make and maintain customer specific changes to a generic product gives more satisfied customers.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - it's not generic.

Comment: @JonH It should have been as part of being cut out to be a separate product.